# Decimal to Binary C++

Tags: c++, binary

I am well aware that there are some duplicated questions on this topic, though each that I find do not resolve my issue. For one I can not use any special libraries besides the `iostream` , `iomanip` , and `string`. So what I have so far is this

```
int DecToBin(int num)
{
    int bin = 0;
    while (num > 0)
    {
        bin += (num % 2);
        //cout << bin << endl;  this is used for debugging purposes
        num = num / 2;
    }
    return bin;
}
```

And I call it like so

```
 int binary = DecToBin(170);
 cout << binary << endl;
```

Except I keep getting 0, which I believe is because of the data type I set it too. So my question is how do I get the correct output to come? Also my results should be

```
10101010 is base 10 of 170
```

Comment: Can be done very easily using [`std::bitset::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: Is this already preexisting or needs a library?

Comment: @EasyBB It comes out of `#include <bitset>` which is included in the standard C++ library

Comment: _"Is this already preexisting or needs a library?"_ It's a c++ standard function (as the `std` suggests). Check the linked reference.

Comment: I can't include bitset, as our professor has not gone over this, so thanks for the good read though mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cyber's answer technically fixes the issue, I think it would not hurt to explain your misunderstanding. Your function `DecToBin` does not convert decimal to binary, but rather binary to some strange binary format which being printed as decimal gives you binary representation. Problem is that numbers already stored in binary format and it was converted to binary either by translator (if you used constant in your source code) or by io library, if you used `std::cin` to input. The same library converts it back to decimal (by default) from binary when you print it on the console using `std::cout`, which leads to your idea, that number is stored in decimal format.

So technically your solution works but I am not sure that your professor would accept it as it shows that you do not understand the concept (I would not). Proper solution would be to convert int to binary string and then output it to `std::cout`:

```
std::string binary( unsigned int n )
{
    std::string s;
    for( ; n > 0; n /= 2 )
       s = std::to_string( n % 2 ) + s;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
     int n = 170;
     std::cout << "binary representation of " << n << " is " << binary( n )
               << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Except the problem of some of your code the professor does not like things that he has not taught. Which I do a lot because I've been programming for a while, c++ I am new at and so I've been reading the docs, and such cases are eof() and unsigned, long, double, to_string I mean literally he just taught them size and length lol thanks for your post though mate.